# Populating and synchronizing a ComboBox with an ObservableMap?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, hashmap, javafx-8

I am using a singleton as a false database of Employee objects.

In this pseudo-database, there is an ObservableMap, utilizing the Employees' social security number as their unique key.

I have ComboBoxes, TableViews, and ListViews I would like to populate with this database, as well as make sure that any changes in the database will reflect in these TableViews,Listviews, etc.

ComboBoxes, TVs, and LVs require an ObservableArraylist, however, so how am I supposed to get that out of a HashMap? I could manually extract values out via an iterator and add them to a new ObservableArraylist, but if any changes are made in the database, I would have to manually adjust the ObservableArraylist too. I'd rather have the synchronization be manual.

Any ideas as to what I am supposed to do?

**Edit:**

Apparently this worked (I had to be very specific. Also unsure as to why I have to use the wildcard instead of just  as a generic parameter.

```
    employeeMap
            .addListener((
                    MapChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer, ? extends Employee> listener) -> {
                System.out.println("CHANGED");
            });
```

Comment: At first ComboBoxes, TableViews and ListViews requires ObservableLists, not ObservableArrayLists. And to your question: If you look into the source of ObservableMapWrapper#keySet you can see that it returns an ObservableKeySet. Unfortunately ObservableKeySet is a private class and it does not implements ObservableSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tested, but try something like:

```
ObservableMap<String, Employee> employeeMap = DataBase.getInstance().getEmployeeMap();
ListView<Employee> listView = new ListView<>();
listView.getItems().addAll(employeeMap.values());

employeeMap.addListener((Change change) -> {
    if (change.wasAdded()) {
        listView.getItems().add(change.getValueAdded());
    } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
        listView.getItems().remove(change.getValueRemoved());
    }
});
```

Note now that you must only modify the `ObservableMap` on the FX Application Thread. If you need to modify it on a different thread, you need to wrap the calls to `listView.getItems().add(...)` and `listView.getItems().remove(...)` in a `Platform.runLater(...)`

Comment: The singleton exists in one package, and the controller for the FXML with the ListView exists in another. I can't access the listview from the database class.

Comment: You should have no need to access the listview from the database class; just access both from your controller. It doesn't matter if they're in different packages.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're trying to do! Can you explain how to exactly use these listeners though? The java documentation doesn't really help much and does not provide examples on how to add a listener. The .addListener method takes either an InvalidationListener or a MapChangeListener (both with boggling syntax). Which do I use, and why/how? I'm trying what you put, but I'm getting a compiler error. ("The method is ambiguous...")

Comment: Apparently this worked (I had to be very specific. Also unsure as to why I have to use the wildcard instead of just <Integer,Employee> as a generic parameter.

        employeeMap
                .addListener((
                        MapChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer, ? extends Employee> listener) -> {
                    System.out.println("CHANGED");
                });